# Common OKTA redirect url for 2 separate instances of same application

Tags: redirect, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

We have a common okta instance for two separate environments (DEV and QA and both have diff host names).
Now we are updating okta application redirect URL every time.
I tried to give redirect url without hostname(without hostname, rest of the URL is common for both environments). But OKTA will not allow without host names.

Any work around for it?
I am thinking by code, if we can stop hitting the URL after redirection and read the authorization code, that may help.

Let me know if any solution for this.

Thanks
Rana

Comment: Why don't you just add the redirect URIs for both apps?

Comment: Ideally, you should create two different applications in Okta based on the environment. The audience of the tokens minted for the applications should also be different. You wouldn't want the tokens minted for DEV be used for QA applications.